# r data table diacritics and quotes with :=

Tags: r, data.table, diacritics, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm using `R` `data.table` package, and I've just found out that, when using `:=` operator functional form, it apparently does the same if you place it between single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`) or diacritical "grave" marks (`).

I've tried to search in both `R` and `data.table` documentation/posts, but the only thing I find are topics about problems with strings with diacritics similar questions. I would like to make sure they actually work the same way, and if that's a `data.table` thing or it's some `R` property I didn't know.

Sorry if it has been asked before, but it that's the case I haven't been able to find it.

Thanks, everyone for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specific to data.table. Non-standard symbols in R need to be quoted, this includes operators: see [The Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Operators).

See also `help("'")`:

> Identifiers consist of a sequence of letters, digits, the period (.)
>   and the underscore.
>
> ...
>
> Such identifiers are also known as syntactic names and may be used
>   directly in R code. Almost always, other names can be used provided
>   they are quoted. The preferred quote is the backtick (`), and deparse
>   will normally use it, but under many circumstances single or double
>   quotes can be used (as a character constant will often be converted to
>   a name).

If you quote the function name in a function call, you can use either of these three types of quotes.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed